# Angular 6 and .net Core API in the same Project using Visual Studio IDE Angular Template

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-2.0, angular6, angular-template, visual-studio-templates

Currently, I am doing the Angular Project setup. FYI, I have decided to go with Angular 6 as Front End and .net Core Web API as a backend. But, I am having a few doubts. If you could clarify my doubts would be much appreciated!

I have googled it. but, I can not find the concrete answer for the below questions.

**Questions,**

1. What is the advantages and disadvantages of using Angular 6 and .net Core API in the same Project when compared with making and maintaining them as Different Project Solutions?
2. Among the above two approaches, Which way is more reliable/maintainable for long run/publishing an Angular/Backend app independent of Cloud(Azure or AWS)?
3. What are the advantages/disadvantages of creating angular Projects using Visual Studio angular template when compared with Angular Cli (ng new) command?

**Note:** I am using TFS Version Control.

Your thoughts are much appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Going through the same dilemma @Vignesh